# Mvn project create global variables to use in Java code and set by file

Tags: java, maven, global-variables

I have a maven project and need to use several final global variables several global variables in my Java code. Is it possible to somehow set the variables in the beginning for example together with the mvn install command together. Best case would be if I could write the variables to a file and reference the file at the mvn install command.
If you have any idea on how to do that I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: For what purpose are those variables (apart from that if they are final they are no variables)...

Comment: You might populate the final java variables from some .properties file, placed to `main/resources`. For putting values to this file you can append your maven install command with `-Dvariable1Name="some value" -Dvariable2Name="some value" ...`. Or you can define variable1Name, variable2Name, .. as properties in pom.xml , and setup different values in maven profile. So, you'll be able to apply a group of values just passing the profile id to maven command like `-PprofileId`.

Comment: Those are urls. The whole project is for testing different routes of a program.

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka thx that sounds perfect! Will test it out later

Comment: Another option: you might also read the values from .properties file, but you'll keep multiple files with hardcoded data within a project. And will pass only `-DconfigFileName=fileName1`. And in java you'll read the `System.getProperty('configFileName')` to reference the config file and populate your java variables. But it is less flexible of course..